# Format formly form field

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I want to format a field when the data finally updates the model. The number usually comes back with a decimal point so what I want to be able to do is format it to no decimal point number (parseNumber function does that).

e.g. `vm.model.total` = 34.54

I want to format this number to 34 `on the fly`.

I can't make it work...

```
vm.fields = [
    {
        className: 'row',
        fieldGroup: [
            {
                className: 'col-xs-12',
                key: 'total',
                type: 'input',
                    templateOptions: {
                    wrapperClass: 'row',
                    labelClass: 'col-xs-9 col-sm-3',
                    dataClass: 'col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-right-7',
                    label: 'Total',
                    disabled: true
                },
                formatters: [parseNumber(vm.model.total, 0)]
             }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: It would also help to show your HTML markup and how you are updating the model.

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not match the [examples in the documentation](http://angular-formly.com/#!/example/field-options/parsers-and-formatters)

Your argument to `formatters` field is incorrect. That field is expecting a function, NOT THE RESULT of the function, which is what you have defined here.

You should either use an anonymous function or a named function:

```
formatters: [function(value){ return parseNumber(value, 0); }]
```

or

```
formatters: [removeDecimal]
//...

function removeDecimal(value) {
  return parseNumber(value, 0)
}
```

This is a working example from their own documentation which I have added a formatter to the first name field: https://jsbin.com/hapuyefico/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The number is not formatted then. It's still got a decimal point. I have put console.log inside removeDecimal, above the return and it's not even being called.

Comment: I think the next relevant question then, is how are you updating the model? The official example works and the parsers and formatters indeed get called. So, if yours are not getting called, perhaps something is wrong with the way you are updating the model

Comment: Shouldn't formatters format anything that vm.model.total is dynamically? I thought that when vm.model.total changes formatters will apply the new format automatically.

Comment: This all depends on HOW you are updating the model. Is it an AJAX call? Are you using `$http` or some other AngularJS AJAX provider? If not, it could be that the change is not being recognized by AngularJS. That is why I am asking to see how this is done

Comment: It is indeed an $http request. Other formly forms are updated dynamically, this one is too however not the formatters part. Formatters are not dynamically updated.